# angular service not returning success in controller after the work is done in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am calling a method inside a Service and when the work of service is done it should return to controller with the data, 
and continue the work further, but after the service is called and data is generated the method is controller stops and return error in console:

Error:

```
Error: d is undefined
sendOtp/<@http://xxxxxxx:8087/controller/resources/static/js/controller/mainController.js:71:14
processQueue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:14634:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:14650:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:15916:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:15727:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:16024:13
done@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:10511:36
completeRequest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:10683:7
requestLoaded@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js:10624:1
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('signController', ['$scope','signUpService','$location','$rootScope', function($scope, signUpService, $location, $rootScope) {
$scope.OTP='';

function sendOtp(pNumber, countryId){    

    if(pNumber!==null){
    $rootScope.pNumber = pNumber;
    signUpService.sendPhoneOtp(pNumber,countryId)       
     .then(  
        function(d) {
            /*$location.path('/otp', false);*/
            $scope.OTP = d.response.result.otp;
            console.error('OTP SENT SUCCESSFULLY'+$scope.OTP);
            alert($scope.OTP);

        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching OPT of NUMBER');
        }           
    );
    }else{
        alert("Number can not be empty");
    }

}
```

METHOD INSIDE SERVICE:

```
    function sendPhoneOtp(pNumber,countryId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://xxxxx.com/service/verify/phone',
            data: {
                    phone: pNumber,
                    countryId: countryId
                    }
         }).success(function(response){
             deferred.resolve(response.data);

        }).error(function(errResponse){
             console.error('Error while OTP');
             deferred.reject(errResponse);
        });
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Read about [promise anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) you can just `return $http(...);` instead

Comment: Use `console.log()` to log the `response`, As per error message `d` is `undefined`

Comment: Check in service what is structure of response object you have there. Is `response.data` present?

Comment: i am getting an json object in response. and there are objects within objects @Sangharsh

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` It should show you full object. Does your response object has `data` field is first thing to determine

Comment: Also avoid Promise anti-patterns as @AlonEitan and Andriy pointed

Comment: The error given suggests a different problem than the parameter d being undefined (in that case OP would get `cannot read response of undefined` - the error here suggests a possible problem in a HMTL angular expression - would be helpful to see the relevant template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your `sendPhoneOtp` function to:

```
function sendPhoneOtp(pNumber, countryId) {
  return $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'https://xxxxx.com/service/verify/phone',
           data: {
             phone: pNumber,
             countryId: countryId
           }
         }).then(function(response){
           return response.data;
         }).catch(function(errResponse) {
           console.error('Error while OTP');
         });
  }
```

in deprecated `success` function there is no `data` property, also you do not need to use `$q` service, since `$http` is a promise by itself

Comment: This was really helpful, i didn't not knew that success was deprecated. i copied your code exactly and it worked perfectly as needed, thanks